# how to make a distinction for float vs integer (after some computation) for conditional statement?

Tags: python, integer

I have some `integers x,y,z` ; and let's say that I am doing `a = (x+y)/z.`

And I want to write some code if `a` is an integer, and some other code if `a` is a float (not a whole number).

How can I do this? Because as far as I understand, after doing the above computation, `a` will automatically become a float- so how can I write a condition to make this distinction?

Comment: Perhaps you want to do ```if isinstance(a,float): do_something```,```elif isinstance(a,int): do_something_else```?

Comment: @Sujay `a` will always be `float` in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [float.is_integer()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer)

```
a = 2.0
print(a.is_integer()) # True

a = 2.5
print(a.is_integer()) # False
```

Another option is to check if `a` is equals to `int(a)`, the casting will round down the float to the closest `int`

```
a = 2.0
print(a == int(a)) # True

a = 2.5
print(a == int(a)) # False
```

Comment: This can be imprecise because in the a=int case it cannot work: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_integer'

Comment: @Glauco `a` is always `float` in the OP case.

Comment: @Glauco The `/` operator returns always a float

Comment: That was an example. From my point of view If the computation does not include a / we can encounter the AttributeError. But in this case You are right!

Comment: @Glauco any other arithmetic operation will return an `int` since all the variables are `int`s, there will be no need to check. The OP asks specifically about this case.

Comment: Is there no other way to do this? Surely there must be

Comment: @iffhhf You can do `a == int(a)`, see updated answer.